# Install .NET 3.5 quietly

Tags: .net

How do I install the .NET Framework 3.5 quietly? I mean, is there any command or batch to install it quietly?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [there is](http://maaruthi.wordpress.com/2008/04/03/dot-net-framework-123-silent-installations/):

```
Dotnetfx35.exe /q /norestart
```

Comment: Dotnetfx3.exe /q /norestart  or  dotnetfx.exe /q:a /c:”install /l /q

Comment: may ask if the .net already exist will it replace it or just don't install

Answer (score 0):

http://sojoe.info/2006/12/21/how-to-install-microsoft-net-framework-30-silently/